# How to create a shared disk across two or more virtual machines setup on ESX 4.1

Tags: virtualization, storage-area-network

How to create a shared disk across two or more virtual machines  setup on ESX 4.1 ?

My setup :
1. Created three virtual machines on ESX 4.1
2. All the virtual machines have RHEL5U3 installed.

Question :
I wanted to create one disk of size 2GB and make it shared across above three virtual machines.

Comment: Are you trying to create a template or do you want all three of your virtual machines to mount the same block level device (disk) simultaneously?

Comment: Yes I wanted to mount same block level device on all the virtual machines (guest os) simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

Big giant caveat. You need to disable caching on the vm's to get a consistent view of the shared disk.

disable caching!
disk.locking = "FALSE"
diskLib.dataCacheMaxSize = "0"

This would still require a clustered file system.

While yes it is possible, numerous vmware support documents mention corruption as a recurring theme. 
They also recommend you use a RAW LUN instead of vmdk.
I would use something like drbd to do this.